# Фрагменты или отдельные активити

Tags: android, оптимизация, activity, android-fragment

Только начинаю работать с Android, возник вопрос по поводу оптимизации работы приложения. При возможности реализовать приложение обеими путями, чему стоит отдавать предпочтение: разным активити или построению основной части приложения с использованием фрагментов?
К примеру, имеется простенькое приложение-игра, пусть она будет заключаться в сложении чисел. Приложение состоит из главного экрана, основного экрана игры и страницы с рекордами. Стоит ли это все засунуть с помощью фрагментов в одно активити или лучше разграничить по разным?

Comment: Фрагменты лучше использовать только в крайнем случае. Рекомендую [эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/277289/).

Answer (score 7):

Вопрос того, когда использовать фрагменты, разработчик принимает сам, из соображений необходимости, а не так, чтобы раз есть - значит надо использовать.  Бездумное использование фрагментов только расходует ресурсы устройства в пустую.

Идея фрагментов основана на том, что потребовалась возможность часть кода активити выделить в отдельный самостоятельный блок. Что позволяет, с одной стороны, иметь несколько обособленных блоков в одной активити, с другой - в нескольких активити, один и тот же блок.

Отсюда типичные применения фрагментов:

1. Однопанельный интерфейс на телефоне - двухпанельный (многопанельный) на планшете - то, ради чего все и затевалось в основном.
2. Использование одного отображения, требующего какой то логики  в разных активити (исключение дублирования кода).

Есть еще некоторые решения, где фрагменты оправданы и используются, например, вывод диалоговых окон через фрагмент позволяет удобнее контролировать изменения состояния в процессе работы, такие как поворот устройства.

Общий принцип такой, что если проще не использовать фрагменты - их не надо использовать.

Что касается конкретно вашего случая, то использование фрагментов в такой задаче только запутает и усложнит структуру приложения, ничего, кроме дополнительного геморроя на пустом месте вы тут не выгадаете.

Comment: 1. Единственный знак, вокруг которого пробелы ставятся с двух сторон — это тире. Перед запятыми, точками, двоеточиями пробел не ставится. 2. Пожалуйста, используйте форматирование при помощи параграфов, а не переносов строк. На сайте такой стиль, и полноценные параграфы не выглядят такими слепленными. 3. Для оформления нумерации в виде списка список тоже должен быть отделён от остального текста двумя переводами строки, как и параграфы.

Comment: Насчет запятых , я привык так печатать , не думаю , что это в какой то степени принципиально .. в остальном спасибо , еще не до конца разобрался с этим markdown

Comment: Это не принципиально, конечно, но это неграмотно. Например, можно, ставить, запятую, после, каждого, слова, и, вас, наверное, даже, поймут, в, большинстве, случаев, но, это, сделает, ваш, текст, сложнее, для, восприятия. В общем, я бы советовал переучиваться. Всё-таки отучиться от лишнего пробела — задача простая. Многоточие, к слову, состоит из трёх точек и слева от него тоже пробелы не ставятся. Искренне ваш, грамматический нацист.

Comment: :) Не такая уж простая задача , если печатаешь десятилетиями , под 400 знаков , на автомате .. По хорошему , здесь есть гораздо более достойные кандидаты поучиться грамматике и правописанию , чем некто , ставящий пробел перед запятой .

Answer (score 4):

Если вы задаетесь этим вопросом из соображений производительности, то запихивание всего и вся в одну активити вам вряд ли чем-то поможет. Подобный подход скорее поможет вам получить корявую структуру интерфейса, нежели извлечь какую-то пользу.

Кроме того, как говорил один умный человек, преждевременна оптимизация лишь немногим лучше, чем  убийство маленьких котят. 
Ну, на самом деле он говорил не так, но это неважно