# Как по нажатию на пункты меню показывать те или иные экраны?

Tags: java, android, activity

Как организовывается "архитектура активити" в проектах?

Есть у меня активити *A*, к которой я приделал красивое фрагментовое меню слева. Соответственно, по нажатию на пункты этого меню я хочу показывать те или иные экраны.

Как мне это делать?

На каждый экран создавать свою активити и к каждой из них приделывать мое меню, или использовать одну *активити* с этим меню и динамически подгружать на нее разные слои?

Comment: красивое фрагментовое меню слева, это что  - `NavigationDrawer`? Все зависит от того, какой контент должны содержать эти "экраны". Если "экраны" разные по действиям\оформлению, то использовать разные активити (или, как вариант, разные фрагменты в одной активити), если  меняется только содержание, а оформление и логика работы одинаковые, то использовать одну активити и менять только данные. Для точного ответа в вопросе недостаточно информации - что за "экраны", что должны содержать ..

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно отображать один и тот же фрагмент на разных активностях, то делать новые активности с этим(и) фрагментом(ми) не имеет смысла. Для решения такого вопроса целесообразно использовать фрагменты. Они позволяют добиться хорошей модульности и гибкости пользовательского интерфейса. Вот [ссылка на документацию](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/fragments.html), ознакомьтесь, возможно вам лучше использовать их.

А вот [туториал](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/activity.php) по переходу между активностями.

Так что всё по большей части зависит от вашего контента. Я предлагаю на одной активности отображать фрагмент вашего меню и фрагменты контента вашего приложения. Это более гибко.

Comment: с другой стороны [нет никакой надобности](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419061/177345) использовать фрагменты просто потому, что они есть. :)

Comment: @pavlofff пункт 2 по вашей ссылке : Использование одного отображения, требующего какой то логики в разных активити (исключение дублирования кода). Я думаю это подходит под описание автора, а именно меню. Думаю фрагменты здесь уместны.

Answer (score -1):

у вас есть *активити*, к нему и приделывайте *layout*.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].