# Быстродействие при переключении Activities Android

Tags: java, android, activity

Есть активити, в котором основной есть кнопка и есть `OnClickListener` для нее:

```
CustomView login_skip =  (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.login_skip);
login_skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(FirstLaunchActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Дело в том, что этот код выполняется 3-5 секунд и только тогда открывается новое `Activity`.

В чем может быть проблема быстродействия?

Нужно ли использовать `Fragment`, вместо `Activity`?

Comment: Видимо дело в анимации перехода между активити.  В вашем коде нет ничего, что могло бы занять три секунды на выполнение. [Решение о использовании фрагментов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419061/177345) принимается из оправданости их использования о чем судить из вашего вопроса невозможно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Оптимизация метода onCreate android](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471754/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-oncreate-android)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте убрать анимацию :

```
 overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

перед `finish()`