# Оптимизация метода onCreate android

Tags: java, android, оптимизация

У меня есть несколько активити в приложении, но переключение между ними занимает 3-5 секунд (слишком долго). 
Я пытался оптимизировать код с помощью `AsyncTask` и `Threads`, но бзуспешно. Как  можно ускорить загрузку?

Код запуска нового активити:

```
onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(FirstLaunchActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

`onCreate` метод нового активити:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Setting Content View
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXIT_KEY, false)) {
            finish();
        }

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mSignInProgress = savedInstanceState
                    .getInt(SAVED_PROGRESS, STATE_DEFAULT);
        }

        mClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
        settings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        settingsVK = getSharedPreferences(VK_PREFERENCES, MainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);

// Load Navigation Drawer
        getDrawer(
                settingsVK.getString(VK_INFO_KEY, ""),
                settingsVK.getString(VK_EMAIL_KEY, "")
        );

/** GOOGLE **/
        mSignInButoon = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mSignInButoon.setOnClickListener(this);

        mSignOutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
        mSignOutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
/****/

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(JUST_SIGNED_KEY, false))
            initDialog_share();

        // Get and set system services & Buttons & SharedPreferences & Requests
        inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        vk_sign_out = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.vk_sign_out);
        vk_sign_out.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstLaunchActivity.class)
                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                        finish();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        settings
                                .edit()
                                .putBoolean(SIGNED_IN_KEY, false)
                                .putString(PROFILE_PHOTO_LOCATION_KEY, "")
                                .apply();
                        settingsVK
                                .edit()
                                .putString(VK_PHOTO_KEY, "")
                                .putString(VK_EMAIL_KEY, "")
                                .putString(VK_INFO_KEY, "")
                                .putBoolean(VK_SIGNED_KEY, false)
                                .apply();

                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
        });

        if (!settingsVK.getBoolean(VK_SIGNED_KEY, false)) {
            vk_sign_out.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Мой `layout`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_light"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/grey_light"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_main"/>

            <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/vk_sign_out"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#B71C1C"
                android:enabled="false" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sign_in_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sign_in_button"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#B71C1C"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="@string/sign_out_button_name" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/circles_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
                android:id="@+id/vk_sign_out"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2000dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAppPrimary"
                android:text="VK Sign out"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/plus_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sign_out_button"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sign_out_button"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_light"
                android:text="@string/plus_signed_id"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/plus_user"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sign_out_button"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/plus_text"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_light"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/shadow"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_shadow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Вы пробовали на разных устройствах? В вашем коде нет ничего, что должно было бы работать долго. Проще говоря, оптимизировать нечего.

Comment: А что делает `buildGoogleApiClient()` и что такое `initDialog_share()`?

Comment: @Barmaley, `buildGoogleApiClient()` - авторизация через Google+, используется только при нажатии кнопки. `initDialog_share()` - простая инициализация диалогового окна, используется сразу после входа.

Comment: @metalurgus, пробовал. Если на устройстве меньше 1 ГБ оперативной памяти, то `OutOfMemoryError`. Тогда почему такая задержка?

Comment: если так, то у вас проблема с `layout`. Скорее всего именно он крайне неоптимальный

Comment: @metalurgus, добавил свой `layout`. В `FrameLayout`ничего нету, специально временно все убрал.

Comment: У меня версий кроме `buildGoogleApiClient()` и `initDialog_share()` - попробуйте закомментить

Comment: У вас `ListView` лежит внутри `ScrollView`. Что это за извращение? Если у вас в `ListView` 100500 элементов, тогда `OutOfMemoryError` вполне ожидаемо произойдет. И рендериться это все будет очень долго

Comment: @metalurgus, в `ListView` нету ничего,  т.к. пользователь еще не авторизовался