# android создание многооконного приложения

Tags: android

Хочу сделать прогу наподобие алиэкспресс, почти с таким же функционалом
Сразу скажу, я начинающий в андроиде, но знаю js php, c# немного, т.е. собственно прогать умею.

Как сделать многооконное приложение? На одних сайтах пишут что с помощью фрагментов, на других что фрагменты это нот гуд и можно сделать все в одном активити

Будут страницы магазина, отдельного товара и на них кнопки шаринга, соот-но нужно сделать для каждой страницы свое активити?
Укажите пожалуйста направление

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы планируете использовтаь `NavigationDrawer` (боковое выезжающее меню), то логичнее такой интерфейс построить на фрагментах с одной хост-активити, реализующей этот дровер и нужным количеством страниц-фрагментов - это будет наиболее оптимальное решение.

Если дровер вы использовать не планируете, то необходимость в фрагментах стоит обдумать более тщательно, сделает ли это вашу разработку оптимальнее. Для простых "экранов" сменяющих друг друга, необходимость фрагментов весьма сомнительна и только усложняет код (особенно при переходе из фрагмента в другой фрагмент и необходимости взаимодействия этих фрагментов).

В любом случае, у вас будет либо несколько активити (для каждого "экрана" своя), либо несколько фрагментов. Организовать несколько экранов в одной активити весьма "дурная" затея, которая обернется только проблемами и напрасно потраченным временем, так как работать такая конструкция не будет.

Ранее я выступал по поводу [необходимости использования фрагментов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419061/177345) и о многооконном приложении [на одной активити](http://4pda.ru/pages/go/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fru.stackoverflow.com%2Fa%2F513812%2F177345&e=56501863), можете почитать, мое мнение на эти вопросы и сейчас не изменилось. То есть вариантов, повторю два: одна активити - много фрагментов или много активити ни одного фрагмента.

Так же рекомендую почитать Б. Харди - "Программирование для профессионалов" - 2016г. 2 издание. Она очень хорошо поможет вам продвинуться в android-разработке и ознакомиться с типовыми практиками на примере разработки реальных приложений, хотя с некоторыми моментами в этой книге я и не согласен, она будет очень полезна начинающему разработчику и в ней вы найдете ответы на все основные вопросы. (а с нюансами разберетесь по мере накопления опыта)

Comment: а можно ли сделать несколько NavigationDrawer activity и меню использовать одно для всех? дабы не копировать

Comment: @user202854 Если вы используете NavigationView, то конечно можете использовать ресурсы вроде navigation_menu.xml или разметки заголовка во многих активити.

Comment: @user202854 Вообще [есть несколько вариантов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608308/177345) для реализации дровера в нескольких активити. Я бы рекомендовал наследование от базовой активити