# Как создать новую активность с NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, шаблоны, android-navigation-drawer

чтоб осталась шторка... интент на `EmptyActivity` создаёт новую активность, но шторка пропадает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Шторка" и не должна появляться из ничего. Чтобы `NavigationDerawer` присутствовал в активити, он должен быть реализован в этой активити, в `EmptyActivity` он не реализован.

Вариантов решения вашей проблемы четыре:

- Самый плохой - в каждой активити реализовать свой `NavigationDrawer`
- Реализовать одну активити с `NavigationDrawer` и из нее вызывать фрагменты для других экранов. Если при этом с фрагментов нужно будет переходить еще на один уровень (вызывать из фрагментов фрагменты), то взаимодействие между ними может стать небольшой проблемой.
- Сделать базовую активити, которая реализует `NavigationDrawer`/ Остальные активити наследовать от этой активити.
- Использовать готовую библиотеку, например [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) от Mike Penz.