# Боковое меню на всех активностях

Tags: android, activity, android-navigation-drawer

Хочу реализовать одно и то же боковое меню на 4 активностях. Перегуглил. В разных статьях все по-разному и я вообще запутался. Я так понял нужна одна разметка (базовая), меняется только контент. В статье одной было написано что нужно создать для каждой активности свой лэйаут с собственной разметкой контента и переопределить метод `setContentView(int)`. Вообщем я ничего толком не понял, помогите допилить идею. Вот разметка

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:background="#512da8"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- меняется только это -->

    </FrameLayout>

<include layout="@layout/navigation_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

И вот переопределенный метод

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int main)
{
    LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) content.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.navigation_view_open, R.string.navigation_view_close);
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    FrameLayout activityContainer = (FrameLayout)drawer.findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(main, activityContainer, true);
    super.setContentView(content);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Лог сейчас

```
DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.
```

Гуглил. `DrawerLayout` у меня в `Layout`. Что не так?

Насчёт фрагментов. Не хочу использовать их. Уж слишком сложно и неудобно будет, контент будет связан между собой и боковой панелью.

Comment: Я не пишу под андроид, нов случае с XAML (а подход к созданию и в андроид и в UWP практически одинаков), я бы сделал так, как вы делать не хотите =) Я бы сделал 2 Grid.ColumnDefinition. В нуловой колонке реализовал меню, а в правой колонке реализовал фреймы, предварительно описав единый стиль, который бы подключал к другим фреймам.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608308/177345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае удобнее всего воспользоваться вот этой библиотекой [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). А стандартная реализация подразумевает, что вы будете менять фрагменты на одной активити

Comment: приведенная вами ссылка не работает

Comment: @pavel163, а как её использовать на нескольких активностях?

Comment: @Сергей Грушин Вам надо будет на каждой активити делать инициализацию. Я бы создал какую-нибудь абстрактную базовую активити с инициализацией панели, и наследовал бы все активити в которой нужна боковая панель от базовой

Comment: @elik У меня работает.

Comment: @pavel163, я уже использую `ViewFlipper` для смены экранов.

Comment: @СергейГрушин `ViewFlipper` не меняет экран, а меняет View на нем. Он работает как `ViewPager`. И лучше уж `ViewPager` использовать вместо `ViewFlipper`