# Navigation Drawer в фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Можно ли создать Navigation Drawer в отдельном фрагменте, если да то как ?
А если нет то как правельнее сделать, просто говорят что подход с фрагментами правельнее.

Comment: Левое меню должно быть в актвити. Зачем его во фрагмент пихать?

Comment: У меня просто сейчас только одно активити, и в нем меняются фрагменты, и сейчас в одном фрагменте должно быть левое меню, а в остальных не нужно, я хотел знать, стоит ли переносить тот фрагмент в активити, или есть какой то другой способ.

Comment: Ну, в теории то можно нужную разметку во фрагмент пихнуть и оно даже должно заработать... Но я бы посоветовал таки в отдельной активити это реализовать.

Comment: Просто раньше было в активити, переносил все в фрагмент потому что говорили что так не годится, мол такой подход не правильный, а теперь оказывается нужно назад переделывать как было.

Comment: Я просто уже запутался какой подход является правильным, и кого слушать. Можно услышать вашу профессиональную точку зрения ?

Comment: Есстесственно есть разные точки зрения на сей счёт. В защиту своей точки зрения могу сказать, что есть не одна либа для полного отказа от фрагментов. Отказываются от них, т.к. когда их много - много боли. Если есть возможность перенести к-л фрагмент в отдельную актвити - лучше так и сделать. Если это, конечно, с точки зрения разделения логики приложения уместно. Единственного верного решения вы не найдёте

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя. А если и можно — не нужно. Я думаю, что Вы немного не так поняли то, что Вам сказали. Хорошей практикой является использовать `NavigationDrawer` в одной активности, помещая в нее любое кол-во фрагментов.

Answer (score 1):

Если часть интерфейса должна содержать `NavigationDrawer`, а другая - нет, то самым правильным решением будет разделить интерфейс минимум на две активити, одна из которых реализует `NavigationDrawer` и хостит фрагменты, которые тоже должны реализовать этот дровер, вторая - не реализует его и, при необходимости, хостит фрагменты, которые тоже не должны реализовать дровер, но связаны цепочками переходов или же переходит на другие активити, которые тоже не реализуют дровер.

Так же, если дровер должен реализовать только один экран, то использование фрагментов вообще сомнительно. Еще стоит заметить, что [есть решения с дровером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/608308/edit) и несколькими экранами, которые не используют фрагментов.

В конце мое мнение о том, [как определиться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419061/177345), нужны ли вам в вашем приложении фрагменты вообще