# Fragment и его использование на практике

Tags: java, android

Объясните суть использования `Fragment`, плюсы и минусы.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/277289/

Comment: Здесь аргументы против их использования

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419061/177345

Answer (score 2):

В двух словах и не расскажешь. Фрагменты это возможность в какой-то области экрана менять целый блок содержимого. Затем, при смене ориентации устройства или при отображении этого же приложения на устройстве с большим экраном - менять местами, добавлять или убирать с экрана эти блоки (фрагменты).